# Comment exprimer être « primed » pour quelque chose ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Mieux expliqué par an exemple tout simple :

> Non je ne pense pas que tu as vu un fantôme. Tu as entendu un ruissèlement et vu une lumière, et tu t'es convaincu que tu l'as vu parce que tu était "primed" de/à le voir !

Donc, le sentiment exact que je souhaite exprimer est l'état d'être prêt à voir/faire quelque chose à cause d'un biais au préalable, intentionnel ou pas.

Les mots qui viennent à l'esprit sont ainsi : prêt, préparé, biaisé, etc., mais je ne pense pas qu'ils donnent ce que je veux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a un terme général.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9dispos%C3%A9)) **prédisposé** A. − [Accompagné ou non d'un compl. dir. désignant une pers.] Prédisposer (qqn) à + inf. ou subst.Mettre (quelqu'un) dans des conditions favorables à (accomplir ou apprécier) certaines choses.

- Non je ne pense pas que tu as vu un fantôme. Tu as entendu un ruissèlement et vu une lumière, et tu t'es convaincu que tu l'as vu parce que tu étais *prédisposé* à le voir !

Il existe un terme plus fort, péjoratif. Le conditionnement peut être de l'auto-conditionnement conscient ou non et n'a pas à être le fait d'un agent indépendant de la personne concernée.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/conditionner)) **conditionné**  (Péjoratif) Exercer une influence sur les idées et le comportement de quelqu'un, à son insu.

- Non je ne pense pas que tu as vu un fantôme. Tu as entendu un ruissèlement et vu une lumière, et tu t'es convaincu que tu l'as vu parce que tu étais *conditionné* à le voir !

([réf. Astrologie de l'âme: Découvrez votre mission de vie -](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Astrologie_de_l_%C3%A2me/eN9BEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22conditionn%C3%A9+%C3%A0%22&pg=PA161&printsec=frontcover) ) Je suis conditionné à un comportement social déformé par une hypocrisie relationnelle.

([réf. Cahier Dr Good ! Je me prépare à la naissance !](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cahier_Dr_Good_Je_me_pr%C3%A9pare_%C3%A0_la_nais/BFWIEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22conditionn%C3%A9+%C3%A0%22&pg=PT88&printsec=frontcover)) Il est conditionné à faire l'équation douleur = danger. Donc, quand votre cerveau vit une contraction, il se dit : alerte, danger, douleur. Une solution ? La fuite. Sauf que ce n'est pas possible. Autre solution ?

([réf. Psychologie des émotions : Série LMD](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Psychologie_des_%C3%A9motions_S%C3%A9rie_LMD/C4pIEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22conditionn%C3%A9+%C3%A0%22&pg=PT99&printsec=frontcover)) Un autre patient dont l'amygdale est intacte et l'hippocampe est lésé présente un pattern de résultats inverse, il est incapable de dire quel transparent était suivi du bruit, mais est susceptible d'être conditionné à la peur.

Il existe enfin un terme littéraire, similaire à « prédisposé ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enclin)) **enclin** Littér. [S'applique à un être animé et, plus fréquemment humain; toujours accompagné d'un compl. généralement introduit par à, quelquefois par vers, et désignant un comportement, une manière d'être] Qui est porté, comme par prédisposition naturelle, à.

- Non je ne pense pas que tu as vu un fantôme. Tu as entendu un ruissèlement et vu une lumière, et tu t'es convaincu que tu l'as vu parce que tu étais *enclin* à le voir !

([réf. Les théories hellénistiques de la douleur](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_th%C3%A9ories_hell%C3%A9nistiques_de_la_doul/-IfjQKfB_NcC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22enclin+%C3%A0+voir%22&pg=PA280&printsec=frontcover)) Autrement dit , le sujet est alors enclin à voir les choses plutôt de telle manière que de telle autre .

Le meilleur choix dépendra du contexte, de la situation de la personne dont il est question.

Comment: Merci beaucoup - je pense que, selon à quel point je veux que ça pique, prédisposé et conditionné sont parfaits !